# Nuget Package Update

Tags: nuget

New to Nuget. May be a very basic question.

I have successfully created and consumed a Nuget Package from my Local Nuget Server. Now I want to publish an update, a new revision of the dll from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1. Using the GUI tool how can I push this new version to the client for an optional update?

Comment: Are you using NuGet Package Manager?

Comment: Yes, using package manager. I was trying nuget then but now figured out how to push next version. Thanks anyway Rob.